# How to trigger autologin PC from windows form app when PC is logged off

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autologin

I have enabled AutoLogin feature,I am executing commands on PC through C# app with the help of GSM Modem. Now I want to login PC when a specific SMS is received at GSM Modem for this purpose I have turned on AutoLogin option as I did not find any other way. Now I want tou perform AutoLogin when PC is logged off and a specific SMS is received with the Help of C# application. 
How can I do this ?

Comment: I think you're mixing two actions.  By "autologin" I assume you mean at startup the OS (Windows?) automatically logs in with a specified user's credentials?  So when you say you want to "perform Autologin" when an SMS is received you mean you want it to transition from logged off to logged on?  That would be just a "login", not "autologin".  Autologon is usually (only?) triggered by machine startup.  If autologon is enabled then the only way the PC would find itself at the logon prompt would be to start it up and either let it log in and then log it out, or cancel the autologin.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a question you've already asked twice and had closed once before.  My advice, the fact that you happen to want to initiate login through SMS is not significant here.  It could just as well be triggered by the time of day or ambient temperature or phases of the moon.  What you should investigate is how to have a service create an interactive (console?) logon session, which I'm not altogether sure is possible.  Once you have that working, then see about having it triggered by an SMS message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login PC by receiving SMS on GSM Modem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741134/login-pc-by-receiving-sms-on-gsm-modem)